# Problems with scrolling ListView on Windows 8

Tags: listview, windows-8, windows-runtime, scrollviewer

I make some sort of chat application for Windows 8 using C# and XAML.

For chat list I am using ListView binded with ObservableCollection. For message items I am using custom controls, contains RichTextBlock.

I want to scroll ListView to the bottom, to make new messages visible.
Problem that I have faced: 
**ScrollIntoView** method does not make entire message item visible, It makes visible only top of the message item.

So, I also tried solution from [WinRT XAML Toolkit](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/) :
Get ListView's ScrollViewer and use ScrollViewer's methods

```
public static void ScrollToBottom(this ListView listView)
{
   var scrollViewer = listView.GetFirstDescendantOfType<ScrollViewer>();
   scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(scrollViewer.ScrollableHeight);
}
```

and

```
public static void ScrollToBottom(this ListView listView)
{
   var scrollViewer = listView.GetFirstDescendantOfType<ScrollViewer>();
   scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(scrollViewer.ExtentHeight);
}
```

with same effect. Some of message items not scrolled completely.

Also I have tried making delay before scrolling:
     new ManualResetEvent(false).WaitOne(2000);

I haven't more ideas how to make auto-scrollable chat list. How I can do this?

It seems, what Windows Messaging application does not use ListView (StackPanel??):
[image: Windows chat sample]

May be it will be easier to use StackPanel for this?

Comment: Is the ListView animating newly-added elements in? I.e., do they appear full-size, or do they start small and expand to full size, to give the user a visual cue that they're being added? That might explain why even ScrollToBottom doesn't work: you scroll to the bottom, but the item hasn't yet reached its final height, so the Bottom moves a little more as it finishes animating.

Comment: @JoeWhite Yes, where is animation on appearing items. I have tried to set delay 2 seconds before calling scroll methods, but anyway no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have code that will look something like below, where you are adding new chat messages to the observablecollection

```
var newChatMsg = new ChatMsg("foo foo bar bar");
messageObservableColllection.Add(newChatMsg);
```

all you need to do is add the following line of code right after the all to Add()

```
this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                listbox1.ScrollIntoView(newChatMsg);
            });
```

This will put a call to scroll the ListView to the most recently added chat message on the dispatcher queue, which will fire at some point after the INofityProperty has fired and updated the ListView with the new message. This is important in case there are any animations that need to run when an item is added or removed.

Finally, if the item is not completely scrolling into view you may have an issue with the item height. There is an override for ScrollIntoView that lets you specify the edge of the frame that you want the content aligned to. You can also manually specify an additional amount to scroll if you want a particular child element displayed. For more information see this MSDN forum post:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/24e91a3e-6cd3-468b-97eb-c90f39532aba